# Grouping and OR in regex

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> p='a+(\sb)|b+(\sa)'
>>> m=re.search(p, 'b a')
>>> m.group()
'b a'
>>> m.group(1)
>>> 
>>> m=re.search(p, 'a b')
>>> m.group()
'a b'
```

I use `|` as OR, and make one group on both sides of `|`. I wonder why the group isn't captured in `m.group(1)`? Thanks.

**Edit:** I want to match one regex (with one group) in a text. I also want to match another regex (with one group)  in the text. Whichever regrex matches first in the text, I will choose the group of that match (i.e. if I were matching each regex separately, I would pick out group 1 of the matched regex). I thought OR the two regrex's would work. But it doesn't, what would you do if you were me?

Comment: Because group 1 does not contain the matched pattern in `b a`

Comment: can we use  a single way to refer to the group on the sides which matches? See my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way would be the [**branch reset**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset) feature using Python's [**regex**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module.

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.search(r'(?|a+(\sb)|b+(\sa))', 'b a')
>>> m.group()
'b a'
>>> m.group(1)
' a'
>>> m = regex.search(r'(?|a+(\sb)|b+(\sa))', 'a b')
>>> m.group()
'a b'
>>> m.group(1)
' b'
```

As stated in the documentation:

> Group numbers will be reused across different branches of a branch reset... eg. `(?|(first)|(second))` has only group **`1`**.

The conditional regular expression considered a *duplicate subpattern group* share the same number in any subpatterns in `( .. )` in such a group. If  the condition is satisfied, the first pattern is used; otherwise the second pattern is used.

Comment: Thanks. but I only want to capture part of either side, not the whole side.

Comment: Thanks. The website is good. But are there books mentioning branch reset? I searched in some books (not necessarily Python's regex), but didn't find them. Maybe a different name? Or is this a new feature in regex (not necessarily Python's regex)?

Comment: [The earlier link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) is also good, and I hope how to download the pages as a book, but don't know how. (Can't afford the donation)

Answer (score 1):

Because the groups are defined in compilation time using the order they appear on the source regex. Your regex has in fact two groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has two groups. You need to printout the second group because the second group only do the capturing.

```
>>> import re
>>> p='a+(\sb)|b+(\sa)'
>>> m=re.search(p, 'b a')
>>> m.group()
'b a'
>>> m.group(1)
>>> m.group(2)
' a'
>>> m=re.search(p, 'a b')
>>> m.group()
'a b'
>>> m.group(1)
' b'
>>> m.groups()
(' b', None)
```

Use `groups()` to print all the captured group contents.

**Update:**

You could create a function to remove the `None` part present inside the `m.groups` function.

```
>>> def extract_group(tup):
        return [i for i in tup if i is not None]

>>> p='a+(\sb)|b+(\sa)'
>>> m=re.search(p, 'b a')
>>> m.group()
'b a'
>>> print(extract_group(m.groups()))
[' a']
>>> m=re.search(p, 'a b')
>>> print(extract_group(m.groups()))
[' b']
```

Comment: can we use a single way to refer to the group on the sides which matches?

Comment: if you don't know  which group do the capturing, then you could use `groups()` function like above.

Comment: @Tim What exactly you are trying to do? Your RegEx is fine, you just have to understand how Python represents the groups.

Comment: i'm wondering why the last `m.group(1)` in your code doesn't print anything. It have to print `space b`.

Comment: @the: I want to match one regrex in a text, and if matches, pick out group 1. I also want to match another regrex in the tex, and if matches, pick out group 1. Whichever regrex matches first in the text, I will choose group 1 of that match. I thought OR the two regrex's would work. But it doesn't, what would you do if you were me?

Comment: how group 1 picks up the non-matched characters? it prints out the contents of a partcular group only if there is an capturing operation occurs.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It doesn't have to, it actually returns `None`, try `type(m.group(1))`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), `If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that did not match, the corresponding result is None`

Comment: @thefourtheye yep that why it returns none for the second group . `m.groups() (' b', None) `

Comment: @AvinashRaj Use `is not None`, instead of `!= None`